How to use the Properties configuration file during spring aot processing
I want to use the configuration of MybatisProperties (corresponding to application.yml) during aop processing, but I have been unable to obtain the corresponding value
public class MybatisBeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution implements BeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution {

    private final MybatisProperties mybatisProperties;

    public MybatisBeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution(MybatisProperties mybatisProperties) {
        this.mybatisProperties = mybatisProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyTo(GenerationContext generationContext, BeanFactoryInitializationCode beanFactoryInitializationCode) {
        log.info("MybatisBeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution {}", mybatisProperties.getMapperLocations());

        RuntimeHints hints = generationContext.getRuntimeHints();

        String[] mapperLocations = mybatisProperties.getMapperLocations();
        if (mapperLocations != null) {
            log.info("mapperLocations-{}", mapperLocations);
            Stream.of(mapperLocations).map(item -> item.replace("classpath:/", "")).forEach(hints.resources()::registerPattern);
        }
    }

}

How to normally read the configuration bean file for AOT processing
the problems encountered：
The mapperLocations read during the aot processing phase are empty.
desirable results:
The value of mapperLocations can be read normally during the AOT processing stage
Here is my configuration file:

mybatis:
  configuration:
    map-underscore-to-camel-case: true
    log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl
  mapper-locations: classpath:/mapper/*.xml


As far as I know, Spring beans aren't properly initialized during AOT processing so that's just not loaded at that point (only at runtime).

Yes, only BeanDefinitions information will be available. I found the answer in the spring community

If you found the answer to your question, you can answer it yourself. But if you do, please actually provide the answer to the question in your answer and don't just post a link-only answer (linking your sources is highly appreciated (and required) but your answer should still be self-contained/still be applicable if the link doesn't work).

Yes, I was just providing my answer

Answer here 
You can manually bind MybatisProperties through environment to obtain objects
@Slf4j
public class MybatisBeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution implements BeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution {

    private final Environment environment;

    public MybatisBeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyTo(GenerationContext generationContext, BeanFactoryInitializationCode beanFactoryInitializationCode) {

        MybatisProperties mybatisProperties = Binder.get(environment)
                .bind("mybatis", Bindable.of(MybatisProperties.class))
                .get();
        log.info("properties.getMapperLocations()");
        log.info("{}", mybatisProperties.getMapperLocations());
        log.info("properties.getMapperLocations()");

        String[] mapperLocations = mybatisProperties.getMapperLocations();

        RuntimeHints hints = generationContext.getRuntimeHints();
        if (mapperLocations != null) {
            log.info("mapperLocations-{}", mapperLocations);
            Stream.of(mapperLocations).map(item -> item.replace("classpath:/", "")).forEach(hints.resources()::registerPattern);
        }
    }

}

result:
2024-12-05 22:17:09.049  INFO 3752 --- [           main][] BeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution : properties.getMapperLocations()
2024-12-05 22:17:09.049  INFO 3752 --- [           main][] BeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution : classpath:/mapper/*.xml
2024-12-05 22:17:09.051  INFO 3752 --- [           main][] BeanFactoryInitializationAotContribution : properties.getMapperLocations()

